# How to properly configure Azure Application Gateway Rewrite URL rule?

Tags: azure, routes, azure-application-gateway

We are using azure application gateway to route requests from `host/client` to the specific client app (.NET Core). This way client1 is routed to `server1/client1` and client2 is routed to `server2/client2` and so on. We are using URL path map to resolve the exact server for each client.

Application gateway has a limitation in 100 paths in URL Path map per listener. This forces us to keep the number of client applications low.
Recently we have rewritten our application to support multiple tenants. So now we can process multiple clients' requests using a single app. Our new routing looks like `server/app/client`. Still, we want to keep end-clients URLs in the same way as those are: `host/client`

My idea was next: Use Application gateway rewrite set, and on request, replace URL path values from `/client` to `/app/client`; But it seems that no matter what I set into those rules I do I keep getting the same response. **It looks to me that rewrite rules are simply ignored. Even the basic one that does not contain any `if` logic.** 
e.g.:

[image: super simple rule]
 -

- **So my question is whether it is possible to update request URL before application gateway rules are applied?**

Will be really glad to get some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved your problem but I had exactly the same !
It looks like Microsoft made some changes few days ago on Application Gateway. And now it works ! But I had to delete my Application Gateway and create it again from scratch.
Hope this will help

Denis